# Why I need to study Matrix and Vectors in maths

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am presently learning  C and C++ programming. I want to make my profession as a C and C++ programmer. Well. In Data structure concepts, I can see lot of matrix material. In  school time, I used to work with matrix and vector concepts in maths subject. At that time, I only learned how to add, subtract and transform the matrix(ces). But still now I really can't understand why I studied those matrix and vector concepts. How will those concepts be useful for real life application usage and programming level usage? My question is "Why do we need to study the concepts of matrices and vectors in maths?"

Comment: Vectors, matrices and tensors give you an idea of how multidimensional array works. They are also used in programming, for applications such as graphics (image rotation, projection, etc), both 2D and 3D.

Comment: Fourier transformation - often used in programming, based on matrix concepts. Cosine transformation (used in JPEG coding) as example.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you *can* see why you need matrices in data structures, but *not* why programmers should learn matrix arithmetic and the like in mathematics?

Comment: The question is not clear, but it seems to me that if at some point in the past there were people who insisted that you study vectors and matrices, then those are the people who can answer your question.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. You're free! You can just stop if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your question depend, in part, on why you are interesting in programming. Are there specific problems you would like to solve or work on? Are there particular application areas in which you would like to work? Some fields, such as scientific computing, data mining, and robotics, to name just a few, can involve heavy use of vectors and matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Because most, well pretty much all of physics is based on vectors. Any physical model/simulation/video game you may want to make as a programmer is going to be using vectors (forces, velocities etc). Pretty much any scientific or science based (yes, that includes video games) use of programming is going to rely on vectors.